# How can I embed any winforms control into a winforms RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

WPF allows you to insert an `InlineUIContainer` into a `System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox`, which can contain any `UIElement`.

Is there an equivalent feature in WinForms? Not just images, but interactive key/mouse controls?

Comment: No, such thing is not a standard feature of WinForms  - it is not possible. You could place an UI element *over* the RTB and then it looks like it is embedded into the RTB and the UI has normal Mouse/Keyboard event handling. Out of curiousity - why would you need another UI element inside the RTB?

Comment: You can make a control a child of RTB but that's where it ends, it isn't going to scroll for example.  RTB has some residual support for OLE, mostly because it was too hard to remove it, but you'll never get it going for controls.  Mouse and keyboard interception is of course not a problem.